# MarkupExtension is not valid for Setter.Value. The only supported MarkupExtension types are DynamicResourceExtension and BindingBase or derived types

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2017, markup-extensions

I have a custom markup extensions "ThemeExtension" to provide "SolidColorBrush" from my DefaultTheme.xaml ResourceDictionary.

Calling example: `BorderBrush="{extensions:Theme Key= FooKeyValue}"`

It is working without any problems on runtime, but SOMETIMES it starting to crash during design time and I can't develop anymore. The designer is crashed. Rebuild, Clean Solution, OS Restart is NOT helping anymore. If I change some value inside of the XAML code it is working for exactly for 1 drawing! And after that it crashes again!

### Preview

[image: preview]

### XAML Stacktrace

```
bei System.Windows.Setter.Seal()
bei System.Windows.SetterBaseCollection.Seal()
bei System.Windows.Style.Seal()
bei System.Windows.StyleHelper.UpdateStyleCache(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, Style oldStyle, Style newStyle, Style& styleCache)
bei System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnStyleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
bei System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
bei System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
bei System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
bei System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
bei System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty(DependencyProperty dp, Boolean preserveCurrentValue)
bei System.Windows.FrameworkElement.UpdateStyleProperty()
bei System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
bei System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
bei System.Windows.FrameworkElement.TryFireInitialized()
bei System.Windows.FrameworkElement.EndInit()
bei System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.EndInit()
bei MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.InitializationGuard(XamlType xamlType, Object obj, Boolean begin)
```

### ThemeExtension.cs

```
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(Color))]
public class ThemeColorExtension : ThemeExtension
{
    internal override object ModifyThemeValue(object value)
    {
        if (value is SolidColorBrush solidColorBrush)
            return solidColorBrush.Color;
        return value;
    }
}

[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(SolidColorBrush))]
public class ThemeExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    // ##############################################################################################################################
    // Properties
    // ##############################################################################################################################

    #region Properties

    // ##########################################################################################
    // Public Properties
    // ##########################################################################################

    /// <summary>
    /// The Key in the Resource Theme file
    /// </summary>
    public string Key { get; set; }

    // ##########################################################################################
    // Private Properties
    // ##########################################################################################

    private static readonly List<ThemeExtension> _Cache = new List<ThemeExtension>();
    private static readonly ResourceDictionary _DefaultTheme;
    private static ResourceDictionary _CurrentTheme;

    private PropertyInfo _Property { get; set; }
    private DependencyProperty _DependencyProperty { get; set; }
    private WeakReference _TargetReference { get; set; }

    #endregion

    // ##############################################################################################################################
    // Constructor
    // ##############################################################################################################################

    #region Constructor

    static ThemeExtension()
    {
        _DefaultTheme = new ResourceDictionary
        {
            Source = new Uri("/HtPlcFramework;component/Themes/DefaultTheme.xaml", UriKind.Relative)
        };
        _CurrentTheme = _DefaultTheme;

        NavigationService.Navigated += _OnNavigated;
    }

    public ThemeExtension() { }

    #endregion

    // ##############################################################################################################################
    // public methods
    // ##############################################################################################################################

    #region public methods

    /// <summary>
    /// https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/931d7bff-90b6-4a70-bb0b-3a097e1301a1/net-40-breaking-change-using-a-markup-extension-as-value-of-property-setter-in-xaml-style?forum=wpf
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceProvider"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        IProvideValueTarget target = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget)) as IProvideValueTarget;
        if (target == null)
            return this;

        if (target.TargetObject != null && target.TargetProperty != null)
        {
            _TargetReference = new WeakReference(target.TargetObject);
            if (target.TargetProperty.GetType() == typeof(PropertyInfo))
            {
                _Property = (PropertyInfo)target.TargetProperty;
            }
            else if (target.TargetProperty is DependencyProperty)
            {
                _DependencyProperty = (DependencyProperty)target.TargetProperty;
            }
        }

        if (!_Cache.Contains(this))
            _Cache.Add(this);

        return ModifyThemeValue(_ReadThemeKey(Key));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Change the Theme set
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="themeUri">Default is: new Uri("/HtPlcFramework;component/Themes/DefaultTheme.xaml", UriKind.Relative)</param>
    public static void ChangeTheme(Uri themeUri)
    {
        _CurrentTheme = new ResourceDictionary { Source = themeUri };

        foreach (ThemeExtension reference in _Cache)
        {
            reference._UpdateTheme();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the current theme entry. Can be null!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static object ReadThemeKey(string key) => _ReadThemeKey(key);

    internal virtual object ModifyThemeValue(object value)
    {
        return value;
    }

    #endregion

    // ##############################################################################################################################
    // private methods
    // ##############################################################################################################################

    #region private methods

    private static void _OnNavigated(object sender, string layer)
    {
        _Cache.RemoveAll(ti => !ti._TargetReference.IsAlive);
    }

    private static object _ReadThemeKey(string key)
    {
        try
        {
            return _CurrentTheme[key] ?? _DefaultTheme[key];
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine($"The key '{key}' was not found in {_CurrentTheme.Source}!");
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void _UpdateTheme()
    {
        if (_TargetReference.IsAlive)
        {
            if (_Property != null)
                _Property.GetSetMethod().Invoke(_TargetReference.Target, new object[] { _ReadThemeKey(Key) });
            else if (_DependencyProperty != null)
            {
                DependencyObject dependencyObject = _TargetReference.Target as DependencyObject;
                dependencyObject?.SetValue(_DependencyProperty, _ReadThemeKey(Key));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _Cache.Remove(this);
        }
    }

    #endregion

}
```

### Related VStudio Developer Community post

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/364029/foomarkupextension-is-not-valid-for-settervalue-th.html

### Related post with no solution

[{0} is not valid for Setter.Value. The only supported MarkupExtension types are DynamicResourceExtension and BindingBase or derived types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881020/0-is-not-valid-for-setter-value-the-only-supported-markupextension-types-are)

[VS2010 Custom MarkupExtension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733257/vs2010-custom-markupextension)

---

On the following website is an example of a "Markup Extension":

https://dzone.com/articles/extend-wpf-add-your-own-keywor (Download project example http://raasiel.typepad.com/MyXamlExtensions.zip)

If I run this example, I get also this annyoing exception! So maybe it is a problem with VisualStudio.

Comment: Is it *really* valid to return `this` from `ProvideValue`?  I'm not sure if it's the cause of the problem, but it seems really odd for a markup extension to return its self rather than an instance of some other object that it translated.

Comment: I have added a `Stacktrace` for more details. Return `this` was a solution approach on a msdn forum. And it helped for some weeks. But know the problems starts again. Return `null` instead of `this` gives the same error. Btw. I have tried to debug the `XAML exception` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35206890/6229375) and the `target` was always `!= null`.

Comment: @DominicJonas Did you find any solution to this, because I have nearly exact the problem. I have read the Setter() .Net Framework source and there you can read, that Setter() only accepts  DynamicResourceExtension or BindingBase as value. Custom MarkupExtensions are denied. See the method Seal() in https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Setter.cs,5c676784218bb188

Comment: Awesome! You've shown me the solution with this! The trick is to use the base class `DynamicResourceExtension`! 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/986451/michael) because he pointed me in the right direction

As you can see (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Setter.cs,123) only `DynamicResourceExtension` are allowed in `Setter` as `MarkupExtension`.

So to get arround this ***** error message:

1. Change base class `MarkupExtension` into `DynamicResourceExtension`
2. provide a `foo` resource key (just to get arround the `ArgumentNullException`; see https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/DynamicResourceExtension.cs,43)

```cs
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(SolidColorBrush))]
public class ThemeExtension : DynamicResourceExtension
{

...

    public ThemeExtension() : base("foo")
    {
    }

...

}
```

Comment: I know, it is bit early, but have you already implemented it in your code, tested it and can confirm that your error is gone?

Comment: Yes, the error is gone and I can use the Designer as I expect that.

Comment: Ok, great! In my case it was a different error and it is even weirder. Before you mentioned to use DynamicResource as a base class, I had the same idea yesterday and I ran into my error again. And the solution to my error is really weird and in my opinion a bug in the Setter class. The explanation is too long for a comment. Eventually I will write a longer answer, that may be interesting for the community.

Comment: Dominic, please have a look into the chat. There may or may not be a problem. Once you inherit from DynamicResourceExtension, the ProvideValue function is never be called in my test. This might work with your solution because as you said, you are just only using one style at this point. But the switching between styles could be broken.

Comment: I get the same behavior as Michael. If my markup extension is derived from DynamicResourceExtension and if it is used in a setter in a style definition, then the ProvideValue method is not called. This solution does not work for me.

Comment: What if you declare `ProvideValue()` with `new` instead of `override`? Like `public new object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) { ...`

Comment: @gt still method not called.